# Why does xcodebuild fail when trying to link to test target?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6, xcodebuild

I have an Objective-C Xcode project. Previously, there were no test targets in this project. We added a Swift-based test target and a few basic tests. The project continues to build from the Xcode GUI just fine. However, building from the command line fails when trying to link the test target.

```
% xcodebuild -project Foo.xcodeproj -scheme Foo -configuration AdHoc -sdk iphoneos build

...output...

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/mluton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-hkljicipwnivteazylcxtobonsbc/Build/Intermediates/Foo.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/FooTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FooTests normal armv7
Ld /Users/mluton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-hkljicipwnivteazylcxtobonsbc/Build/Intermediates/Foo.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/FooTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FooTests normal arm64
```

Running the Ld command manually results in this...

```
ld: file not found: /Users/mluton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-hkljicipwnivteazylcxtobonsbc/Build/Intermediates/Foo.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/FooTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FooTests
```

If I navigate to that directory I see the file is indeed **not** there. I do see bunch of AFNetworking related files along with FooTest* files. Most have extensions like `.d`, `.dia`, and `.o`. But there's no `FooTests` which is what the linker is looking for.

If I edit the 'Foo' scheme I see there are two targets in the Build item. Foo and FooTests. If I uncheck everything associated with FooTests then the command line build will work fine.

Has anyone else tried this and run into the same problem? Am I missing a build setting somewhere? Am I asking for trouble by trying to do unit tests for an Objective-C project in Swift?